# Issue with GridView.setAdapter

Tags: android, android-widget

I am working with GridView element, and tried to execute the line:

```
gv.setAdapter(adp);
```

When gv is an instance of GridView, and adp is a ListAdapter. But I get a lint warning says:

> Call requires API level 11 (current min is 7): android.widget.AbsListView#setAdapter

Now,it is correct that [AbsListView#setAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29) require API level 11, however [GridView#setAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29) available since API level 1. So why the lint warns me, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own adapter by extending from BaseAdapter instead of using a ListAdapter. That should work fine.

Comment: This is what I actually did - adp is an instance of class that extending BaseAdapter.